# multiple select - change selecteds depending on option selection with jquery

Tags: jquery

## I have this multiple select

```
<select id="mysel" name="mysel" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
<option>please choose</option>
<option value="!" SELECTED>all</option>
<option value="A">Sel A</option>
<option value="B">Sel B</option>
<option value="C">Sel C</option>
<option value="D">Sel D</option>
<option value="E">Sel E</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is:

- whenever one of the options 'Sel A'-> 'Sel E' is selected, then unselect option 'all'
- if option 'all' is selected, unselect all other options

I tried with $("#mysel").change() as well with $("#mysel option").click(), but it did never work as expected.

Thanks for your hints

Fabian

Comment: Could you set up an example (jsfiddle, for instance), demonstration the issue? Maybe explain in more detail, what you've tried, and why it does not do what you expect.

Comment: `$("#mysel").change() ` should work here, you can use it to catch the change event, check for selected items and deselect any options you want. What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: You can think of having a radiogroup with two options. First is all, and second is any combination of A-E. So if 'all' is selected, deselect all others. Is any of A-E selected, deselect all.

Comment: I added an example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fabs07/rokfzxwd/). At start 'all' is selected. Use CTRL+any other option. Works fine as 'all' is deselected. Now do CTRL+all. This should select 'all' and deselect all others, but it does not, as the change event on #mysel does not know which option was selected at last. And my tries to get it run not on select but on options don't work at all.

Comment: I forgot to say: in real this is a jquery mobile site where a multiple select is changed into a dialog with checkboxes. But problem is just the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the easiest way, but at least it does what I wanted to do:

```
$("#mysel option").click(function() {
    var str = "";
    $( "#mysel option:selected" ).each(function() {
        str += this.value;
    });
    if (str == "") {
        $( "#mysel option" )[1].selected = true;
    } else if (this.value == "!") {
        $( "#mysel option:selected:not(:first)" ).each(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('selected');
        })
    } else {
        $( "#mysel option" )[1].selected = false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fabs07/rokfzxwd/

Fabian